# Excel formula to reference current cell itself

Tags: excel

I'd like build a formula that can full fill the following:

1) It does a VLookup.  If the VLookup returns a value, assign the value to the cell.
2) Otherwise, keep the current value of the cell.

Is this even possible?  As by default, Excel formula won't allow reference to the current cell.  Thanks!

Comment: The only way to (artificially) do so is by doing the vlookup twice, i.e. `if(vlookup(...)=X, vlookup(...), ...)`.

Comment: The problem is not VLookup.  The problem is how to keep the current value of the cell as I don't want to overwrite it if VLookup returns nothing.

Comment: My point *wasn't* specifically about the vlookup. I could have made my comment even more general for sure. Anyway, if the "current value of the cell" is hard-written, what you want to do is impossible. As explained in @Gary'sStudent answer, you necessarily need a "helper" cell somewhere. Also, note that none of your tags is related to [vba], which in such a case would lead to other conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

Use a "helper" cell.

Place your "default value" in a separate cell, say **Z100**.  Then in **A1** something like:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,C1:D8,2,FALSE),Z100)
```

So if the *VLOOKUP()* works, you get the result; otherwise the default value.

**EDIT#1:**

Take a typical cell, say **A1**.  The current value of the cell will be one of three things:

1. empty
2. a constant *(like "Hello World")*
3. a formula *(like =B56+2)*

Our suggestion is to replace the cell's contents with one of three formulas:

1. `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,C1:D8,2,FALSE),"")`
2. `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,C1:D8,2,FALSE),"Hello World")`
3. `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,C1:D8,2,FALSE),B56+2)`

If you already have hundreds of cells that you need to modify, then use a VBA macro to perform the edits.

Comment: Why the helper cell? Why not paste `Z100`'s formula directly into the `IFERROR`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey  Good suggestion..........post a separate answer and I will up-vote it.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no "default value" for the cells.  Each cell may have different contents.  I guess I'll have to find another way.  Thanks!

Comment: @Helloguys  Then see Aran-Fey's suggestion.

Comment: Sorry for being dumb, but how may I preserve a cell's current value without referencing the cell itself?  (which is disallowed by Excel).

Comment: @Helloguys  You are **not** being dumb.  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: I see.  My cells are mostly #2 above.  I was hoping to reference the cell itself as the 2nd argument of IFERROR.  It's not supported by Excel.  I with Excel had something like `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,C1:D8,2,FALSE), SELF)`.  But anyway, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of accessing the previous value in a cell: but none of them are ideal.
see
https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-8-getting-the-previously-calculated-value-from-the-calling-cells/

Answer (score -1):

It seems only a circular reference is required. Wrap your VLOOKUP in IFERROR with default to the cell.